# can't see the transfer

Tags: money-transfer, money

I payed to this site but in my computer account I can't see the transfer please help me .

[image]

Comment: According to blockchain status https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/bc1qqx79l5f9nsfaxdutjnmaymak4mh6fh2k4egw79 Your BTC is already sent to the address, with >4 confirmations. Could you tell me what the site is? A wallet?

Comment: bitcoin wallet buy btc ıts a mobile wallet

Comment: to which website you transferred BTC? You mean *you transferred 0.0028 BTC out from buyBTC*? Or you *transferred 0.0028 BTC into your buyBTC wallet* from another wallet